# Web scraping in multiprocessing with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, multiprocessing, web-crawler

We have a web scraping script that essential:

`fork process upto 5 for list of websites:
    every process retrieves website data`

(In code we have used **os.spawnlp** function for forking 5 processes and used **[requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library of python** for scraping)

Normally, It takes less than a minutes to process on single process for one website. but when it is multi-processed like above, it takes too long time(more than 473 minutes) sometimes to get data. below attaching screenshot of top command output for this issue.

[image]

Does anyone know why it might be hanging every once in a while? And how to debug and solve this issue.